# Configure DB2 on windows. JDBC error

Tags: jdbc, db2

My organisation wants to setup DB2 for our .Net application that links/uses the database setup on a remote desktop with a fixed IP address. Now, I'm trying to setup this DB2 databse using DB2 Express-C and IBM Data Studio and it is unable to connect to the database through the Java connection.

How do I know this? I tried performing a normal SQL operation using a DB2 command window and it worked.

If I try to do the same thing with Data Studio or command line processor, it doesn't work: always throws a 'user ID revoked' error.

I tried reconfiguring environment variables to JDBC4 driver, using it from an administrator account, but nothing works.

Question - How do I make this work properly? is there any guide or tutorial anyone can share to setup db2 express c properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question - how do I configure it properly? What am I missing?

Comment: please post your configuration and the error